# Cassandra approach of RDBMS nested insertions

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I receive regularly two types of sets of data:

Network flows, thousands per second:

```
{
    'stamp' : '2017-01-19 01:37:22'
    'host' : '192.168.2.6',
    'ip_src' : '10.29.78.3',
    'ip_dst' : '8.8.4.4',
    'iface_in' : 19,
    'iface_out' : 20,
    (... etc ..)
}
```

And interface tables, every hour:

```
[
    {
        'stamp' : '2017-01-19 03:00:00'
        'host' : '192.168.2.6',
        'iface_id' : 19
        'iface_name' : 'Fa0/0'
    },{
        'stamp' : '2017-01-19 03:00:00'
        'host' : '192.168.2.6',
        'iface_id' : 20
        'iface_name' : 'Fa0/1'
    },{
        'stamp' : '2017-01-19 03:00:00'
        'host' : '192.168.157.38',
        'iface_id' : 20
        'iface_name' : 'Gi0/3'
    }
]
```

I want to insert those flows in Cassandra, with interface names instead of IDs, based on the latest matching host/iface_id value. I cannot rely on a memory-only solution, otherwise I may loose up to one hour of flows every time I restart the application.

What I had in mind, is to use two Cassandra tables: One that holds the flows, and one that holds the *latest* host/iface_id table. Then, when receiving a flow, I would use this data to properly fill interface name.

Ideally, I would like to let Cassandra take care of this. In my mind, it seems more efficient than pulling out interface names from the application side every time.

The thing is that I cannot figure out how to do that - and having never worked with NoSQL before, I am not even sure that this is the right approach... Could someone point me in the right direction?

Inserting data in the interface table and keeping only the latest version is quite trivial, but I cannot wrap my mind around the 'inserting interface name in flow record' part. In a traditional RDBMS I would use a nested query, but those don't seem to exist in Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I can hope that the data hourly received in interface table is not too big. So we can keep that data (single row) in memory as well as in cassandra database. For every hour, the in memory data will get updated as well as a new inserted in to database. We can save interface data with below table definition -

```
     create table interface_by_hour(
        year int,
        month int,
        day int,
        hour int,
        data text, -- enitre json string for one hour interface data.
        primary key((year,month,day,hour)));
```

Few insert  statements --

```
    insert into interface_by_hour (year,month,day,hour,data) values (2017,1,27,23,'{complete json.........}');
    insert into interface_by_hour (year,month,day,hour,data) values (2017,1,27,00,'{complete json.........}');
    insert into interface_by_hour (year,month,day,hour,data) values (2017,1,28,1,'{complete json.........}');
```

keep every hours interface data in this table and update it in memory as well. Benefit of having in memory data is that you don't have to read it from table thousand of time every second. If application goes down, you can read the current/previous hour data from table using below query, and build the in memory cache.

```
    cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from interface_by_hour where year=2017 and month=1 and day=27 and hour=0;

     year | month | day | hour | data
    ------+-------+-----+------+--------------------------
     2017 |     1 |  27 |    0 | {complete json.........}
```

Now comes the flow data --

As we have current hour interface table data cached in memory, we can quickly map interface name to host. Use below table to save flow data.

```
    create table flow(
    iface_name text,
    createdon bingint, -- time stamp in milliseconds.
    host text, -----this is optionl, if you want dont use it as column.
    flowdata text, -- entire json string 
    primarykey(iface_name,createdon,host));
```

Only issue I see in above table is that it will not distribute data evenly across the partitions, if you have too many flow data for one interface name, whole data will inserted in to one partition.

I designed this table just to save the data, if you could have specified how you going to use this data, I would have done some more Thinking.

hope this helps.

Comment: I like the approach of storing the hourly JSON object directly for interfaces. It also allows to 'look back' if something went wrong when inserting a flow, rather than using only the last value.

Comment: just take into account that 10MB json data is bad for cassandra, don't just save it raw, use structures or save it to a number of different chunks and it will be o.k. Usually don't go much over 10 or 100k per chunk also use time to live because going too much in history might cost you a lot of storage.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as far as I can tell the interface data is not so heavy on the writes that it would need partitioning by time. It changes only once per hour so it's not necessary to save data for every hour just the latest version. Also I will assume that you want to query this in some way I'm not sure how so I'll just propose something general for interface and will threat the flows as time series data:

```
create table interface(
    iface_name text primary key,
    iface_id int,
    host text, 
    stamp timestamp
);

insert into interface(iface_name, iface_id, host, stamp) values ('Fa0/0', 19, '192.168.2.6', '2017-01-19 03:00:00');
insert into interface(iface_name, iface_id, host, stamp) values ('Fa0/1', 20, '192.168.2.6', '2017-01-19 03:00:00');
insert into interface(iface_name, iface_id, host, stamp) values ('Gi0/3', 20, '192.168.157.38', '2017-01-19 03:00:00');
```

usually this is an antipatern with cassandra:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from interface;

 iface_name | host           | iface_id | stamp
------------+----------------+----------+---------------------------------
      Fa0/0 |    192.168.2.6 |       19 | 2017-01-19 02:00:00.000000+0000
      Gi0/3 | 192.168.157.38 |       20 | 2017-01-19 02:00:00.000000+0000
      Fa0/1 |    192.168.2.6 |       20 | 2017-01-19 02:00:00.000000+0000
```

But as far as I can see you don't have that many interfaces

So basically anything up to thousands will be o.k. here in worst case you might want to
use the token function to get the data out from partitions but the thing is this will save you
a lot on space and you don't need to save this by the hour.

I would simply keep this table in memory also and then enrich the data as it comes in.
If there is updates, update the in memory cache ... but also put writes to cassandra.
If something fails then simply restore from interface table and continue.

basically your flow info would then become

```
{
    'stamp' : '2017-01-19 01:37:22'
    'host' : '192.168.2.6',
    'ip_src' : '10.29.78.3',
    'ip_dst' : '8.8.4.4',
    'iface_in' : 19,
    'iface_out' : 20,

    'iface_name' : 'key put from in memory cache',
}
```

This is how you will get the bigest performance now saving flows is just
time series data then, take into account that you are hitting the cluster
with thousands per second and that when you are paritioning by time you
get at least 7000 if not more columns every second in (with the model
I'm proposing here) usually you will want to have up to 100 000 columns
within single partition, which would say that your partition goes over
ideal size withing 20 seconds or even less so I would even suggest using
random buckets (when inserting just use some number in defined range
let's say 10):

```
create table flow(
    time_with_minute text,
    artificial_bucket int,
    stamp timeuuid,
    host text,
    ip_src text,
    ip_dst text,
    iface_in int,
    iface_out int,
    iface_name text,
    primary key((time_with_minute, artificial_bucket), stamp)
);
```

When wanting to fetch flows over time you would simply use the parts of
a timestamp plus make 10 queries at the same time or one by one to access all the data. There are various techniques here, you simply need to tell more about your use case.

inserting is then something like:

```
insert into flow(time_with_minute, artificial_bucket, stamp, host, ip_src, ip_dst, iface_in, iface_out, iface_name)
    values ('2017-01-19 01:37', 1, now(), '192.168.2.6', '10.29.78.3', '8.8.4.4', 19, 20, 'Fa0/0');
```

I used now just for an example, use https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java to
generate timeuuid with the time when you inserted flow. Also I inserted 1 into artificial bucket, here you would insert random number with range, let's say 0-10 at least. Some people, depending on the load insert multiple random buckets, even 60 or more. It all depends on how heavy writes are. If you just put it to minute every minute a group of nodes within the cluster will be hot and this will switch around. Having hot nodes is usually not a good idea.

With cassandra you are writing the information that you need right away, you are not doing
any joins during write or something similar. Keep the data in memory that you need to
stamp the data with the information that you need and just insert without denormalisation.

Also you can model the solution in a relational way and just tell how you would like to
access the data then we can go into details.

Comment: I was also coming to this conclusion, interface data is indeed not that big (assuming 5000 devices @ 32 interfaces each, it should amount to +/- 10MB every hour) and can be kept in memory.

Comment: If it's 10 MB, it's totally an in memory cache candidate with fallback to cassandra if something goes wrong :) I would not advise gunwant's approach with 10 MB of data in single partition because fetching 10MB from single partition will take long time (multiple seconds) ... but if it's loading after crash It might even be o.k. Once I had around 300kB of data in partition and it really took long time to fetch it.

Comment: I'm now thinking about using an embedded sqlite3 memory database for that.

Comment: this is also an option, Era of Polyglot persistence I guess. imho cassandra is simply just not too good at check then set things.

Comment: Use redis cache instead of sqlite. U can use it hell lot of catching in future.